# Change duration (speed) on a running animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiviewanimation

I am doing an indefinite rotation animation, which works perfectly well when I first start it. What I wanted to achieve was to be able to change the rate of rotation at the runtime. I have this function in animationView:

```
-(void)startBlobAnimation:(float)deltaT
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"Spinning" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:deltaT];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:FLT_MAX];

    CGAffineTransform rotation = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-symmetryAngle);
    blobView.transform = rotation;

    // Commit the changes and perform the animation.
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Calling it with different values of deltaT after the animation was first started doesn't have any effect. If I add `[wheelView.layer removeAllAnimations];` at the start of the function then it successfully stops the animation but doesn't restart it. I also tried using  the block command to start animation, with the same result. I am totally baffled at this point. Could somebody explain what the problem is? Thanks!

Comment: maybe try setting `view.layer.speed`?

Comment: view.layer.speed is, in a word, absolutely not relevant or helpful (which is a bummer).  essentially you have to use the Alex Method - use the presentation layer to get the current value, and essentially restart the anime from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long struggle I came up with a solution that seems to work perfectly and give a smooth transition between animations. Basically I just figure out the current angle of rotation and use it to restart the animation at a different rate. One critical point here is in the last line: you MUST have that `anim.keyPath` there - it can't be Nil (as learned from experience). That way the new animation replaces the old animation, I guess. Oh, and to make it more clear: symmetryAngle is a rotation that makes the object look the same, like 72 degrees for 5-fold symmetry.

```
-(void)startWheelsAnimation:(float)deltaT
{
    float startingAngle = 0.0;

    if(isAnimating) {
        // If animation is in progress then calculate startingAngle to
        // reflect the current angle of rotation
        CALayer *presLayer = (CALayer*)[blobView.layer presentationLayer];
        CATransform3D transform = [presLayer transform];
        startingAngle = atan2(transform.m12, transform.m11);
    }

    isAnimating = YES;

    // Restart the animation with different duration, and so that it starts
    // from the current angle of rotation
    CABasicAnimation * anim = [ CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z" ] ;
    anim.duration = deltaT;
    anim.repeatCount = CGFLOAT_MAX;
    anim.fromValue = @(startingAngle);
    anim.toValue = @(startingAngle - symmetryAngle) ;
    [blobView.layer addAnimation:anim forKey:anim.keyPath];
}
```

Comment: I'll add a code example with the latest Swift etc, for a **restartable animation** - good one.  Great stuff.

Comment: how to get symmetryAngle value ?

Comment: @balkaransingh This question initially came up when I was trying to animate an image of a wheel. Wheels are usually pretty symmetrical. For example if a wheel has 5 spokes then the symmetry angle would be 360 degrees / 5 = 72 degrees. If it has 6 spokes then the angle would be 60 degrees.. You can check out Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotational_symmetry.

Answer (score 1):

## 2017

## Change the speed of a CA animation as it is running.

Here's exactly how I do the "Alex method" ...

I have a shape layer ...

```
@IBDesignable
class SpinningThing: UIView {
    
    public func runAnimation() { // call this from the view controller, say
        speedy = 1.0
        startFastThenSlowDown()
    }
    
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        
        super.layoutSubviews()
        setup()
    }

    func setup() {
        
        setup .. other stuff (draw things)
        setupThingThatSpins()
    }
    
    var thingThatSpins = CAShapeLayer()
    
    var speedy = 0.5        // start fast
    var finalSpeed = 13.0   // final slow speed

    func setupThingThatSpins() {
        
        let p = UIBezierPath( .. etc etc
        thingThatSpins.strokeColor .. etc etc
        // so actually draw the thingThatSpins
    }
```

Here's what happens in `startFastThenSlowDown` ...

```
func startFastThenSlowDown() {
    
    speedy *= 1.175
    animeSpinRestartable(spr: speedy)
    if speedy < finalSpeed {
        delay(0.1) { self._slowDown() }
    }
}
```

Now, here is a **restartable animation** thanks to Alex...

```
func animeSpinRestartable(spr: CFTimeInterval) {
    
    let _key = "animeSpinRestartable"
    
    thingThatSpins.removeAnimation(forKey: _key)
    // is safe the first time through
    
    // get the current angle...
    let t3 = arcs.presentation()?.transform
    let cur = (t3 == nil) ? 0 : atan2(t3!.m12, t3!.m11)
    
    let r = _typicalAnim(keyPath: "transform.rotation.z")
    r.fromValue = cur
    r.toValue = cur + 2 * CGFloat.pi
    r.duration = spr
    
    ///r.isCumulative = true ?  seems unnecessary, so don't do it
    
    thingThatSpins.add(r, forKey: _key)
}
```

In my case, the `thingThatSpins` was a mask (for goodness sake) which was on top of something else (a color gradient, which, in itself animated!)

Good one, OP.

Comment: It's maybe easier to just use CADisplayLink and animate it yourself! But this works perfectly. This seems to be how you restart CA animations in iOS........

Comment: Sorry, I totally missed your addition, as I semi-abandoned my account for a while. But thank you for your kind comments on my approach, and for adding a Swift implementation!

Answer (score -1):

A couple issues--

- <strike>I think for endless animations you will have to use the CoreAnimation API directly.</strike>
   (This is incorrect, you can use UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat)
- Animations are copied to the layer they are applied to, so you can't change them after that (you can replace them however, but you might see a discontinuity)
- You can set `layer.speed` to change the effective animation rate

Here's a working example. Create a new "empty" iOS project in Xcode and replace your AppDelegate like this:

```
@interface AppDelegate ()
@property ( nonatomic, strong ) UIView * animationView ;
@end

@implementation AppDelegate

-(void)buttonClicked
{
    self.animationView.layer.speed = 3.0 - self.animationView.layer.speed ;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    CGRect bounds = self.window.bounds ;
    {
        UIView * subview = [ [ UIView alloc ] initWithFrame:(CGRect){ .size = { 100, 100 } } ] ;
        [ self.window addSubview:subview ] ;

        subview.backgroundColor = [ UIColor orangeColor ] ;
        subview.center = (CGPoint){ CGRectGetMidX( bounds ), CGRectGetMidY( bounds ) } ;

        CABasicAnimation * anim = [ CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z" ] ;
        anim.duration = 1.0 ;
        anim.repeatCount = CGFLOAT_MAX ;
        anim.fromValue = @0.0 ;
        anim.toValue = @(2.0*M_PI) ;

        [ subview.layer addAnimation:anim forKey:nil ] ;

        self.animationView = subview ;
    }

    UIControl * button = [[ UIControl alloc ] initWithFrame:bounds ] ;
    [ button addTarget:self action:@selector( buttonClicked ) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside ] ;

    [ self.window addSubview:button ] ;


    return YES;
}

@end
```

Comment: Thanks! Sorry, took me some time to play with your code. I discovered that apparently layer.speed can't be smaller than 1.0. If I try to set it smaller than 1.0 then the animation just stops. (That's what took me time to figure out). With larger values it works fine. By the way, where can I find the description of 'speed' property? It's not in CALayer reference. What I also realized though is that I can simply run your CABasicAnimation creation code with a different duration, and it works to change the rotation rate unlike my code! So no need in changing layer.speed.

Comment: Oops, I guess I should take the idea of just restarting the animation back. I do indeed get a lot of discontinuity when changing duration. So then the question becomes - Is there a way to throttle rotation rate down to almost zero? (Since the layer.speed can't be smaller than 1.0)

Comment: I guess you'll have to set **animation.duration** to something large instead. **speed** is inherited from the **CAMediaTiming** protocol which **CALayer** implements.

Comment: unfortunately this just does not work - the .speed property is something different altogether.