# circle with dash lines uiview

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I am trying to make a circle with dash lines. I am able to make lines in rectangle but I don't know how to make these in circle. Here is answer I got but it's in Objective-C: [UIView Draw Circle with Dotted Line Border](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35961871/uiview-draw-circle-with-dotted-line-border)

Here is my code which makes a rectangle with dashed lines.

```
func addDashedBorder() {
    let color = UIColor.red.cgColor

    let shapeLayer:CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    let frameSize = self.frame.size
    let shapeRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frameSize.width, height: frameSize.height)

    shapeLayer.bounds = shapeRect
    shapeLayer.position = CGPoint(x: frameSize.width/2, y: frameSize.height/2)
    shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = color
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 2
    shapeLayer.lineJoin = CAShapeLayerLineJoin.round
    shapeLayer.lineDashPattern = [6,3]
    shapeLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: shapeRect, cornerRadius: 5).cgPath

    self.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
}
```

Comment: Did you try using your exact code but change the `UIBezierPath` call to create a circle instead of a rounded rectangle?

Answer (score 12):

Certainly you can just render your circular `UIBezierPath` with the selected dash pattern:

```
class DashedCircleView: UIView {
    private var shapeLayer: CAShapeLayer = {
        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 10
        shapeLayer.lineCap = .round
        shapeLayer.lineDashPattern = [20, 60]
        return shapeLayer
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect = .zero) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        configure()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        configure()
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        updatePath()
    }
}

private extension DashedCircleView {
    func configure() {
        layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
    }

    func updatePath() {
        let rect = bounds.insetBy(dx: shapeLayer.lineWidth / 2, dy: shapeLayer.lineWidth / 2)
        let radius = min(rect.width, rect.height) / 2
        let center = CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.midY)
        let path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: radius, startAngle: 0, endAngle: .pi * 2, clockwise: true)
        shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
    }
}
```

That yields:

[image]

The problem with that approach is that it’s hard to get the dashed pattern to line up (notice the awkward dashing at the “3 o’clock” position). You can fix that by making sure that the two values of `lineDashPattern` add up to some number that evenly divides into the circumference of the circle (e.g. 2π × radius):

```
let circumference: CGFloat = 2 * .pi * radius
let count = 30
let relativeDashLength: CGFloat = 0.25
let dashLength = circumference / CGFloat(count)
shapeLayer.lineDashPattern = [dashLength * relativeDashLength, dashLength * (1 - relativeDashLength)] as [NSNumber]
```

Alternatively, rather than using `lineDashPattern` at all, you can instead keep a solid stroke and make the `path`, itself, as a series of small arcs. That way I can achieve the desired dashed effect, but ensuring it’s evenly split into `count` little arcs as we rotate from 0 to 2π:

```
class DashedCircleView: UIView {
    private var shapeLayer: CAShapeLayer = {
        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 10
        shapeLayer.lineCap = .round
        return shapeLayer
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect = .zero) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        configure()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        configure()
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        updatePath()
    }
}

private extension DashedCircleView {
    func configure() {
        layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
    }

    func updatePath() {
        let rect = bounds.insetBy(dx: shapeLayer.lineWidth / 2, dy: shapeLayer.lineWidth / 2)
        let radius = min(rect.width, rect.height) / 2
        let center = CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.midY)

        let path = UIBezierPath()
        let count = 30
        let relativeDashLength: CGFloat = 0.25 // a value between 0 and 1
        let increment: CGFloat = .pi * 2 / CGFloat(count)

        for i in 0 ..< count {
            let startAngle = increment * CGFloat(i)
            let endAngle = startAngle + relativeDashLength * increment
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: center.x + radius * cos(startAngle), 
                                  y: center.y + radius * sin(startAngle)))
            path.addArc(withCenter: center, radius: radius, startAngle: startAngle, endAngle: endAngle, clockwise: true)
        } 
        shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
    }
}
```

That yields:

[image]

Comment: when i put image in this circle , the contraint doest set to the circle

Comment: I’d suggest using the view debugger and confirm the frame of both the circle view and the image view, and see whether the problem that one or more of the frames is wrong (i.e. you didn’t set up constraints properly) or whether the `CAShapeLayer` for the circle view is is wrong (e.g. you didn’t update the shape layer in `layoutSubviews` or `viewDidLayoutSubviews` like I have above). Once you’ve figured out which of these two issues applies, you can always then post a new, separate question with your findings.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`UIBezierPath(ovalIn:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibezierpath/1624379-init) to create a circle path in a square view.

```
extension UIView {
    func addDashedCircle() {
        let circleLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        circleLayer.path = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: bounds).cgPath
        circleLayer.lineWidth = 2.0
        circleLayer.strokeColor =  UIColor.red.cgColor//border of circle
        circleLayer.fillColor = UIColor.white.cgColor//inside the circle
        circleLayer.lineJoin = .round
        circleLayer.lineDashPattern = [6,3]
        layer.addSublayer(circleLayer)
    }
}
```

Set view background color .clear and fill color of the layer .white

```
class View1: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var circleView: UIView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        circleView.backgroundColor = .clear//outside the circle
        circleView.addDashedCircle()
    }
}
```

Or using [`UIBezierPath(arcCenter:radius:startAngle:endAngle:clockwise:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibezierpath/1624358-init)

```
circleLayer.path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: frame.size.width/2, y: frame.size.height/2),
                            radius: min(frame.size.height,frame.size.width)/2,
                            startAngle: 0,
                            endAngle: .pi * 2,
                            clockwise: true).cgPath
```

[image]

Comment: how to remove white color from sides and should be white under the circle?

Comment: yes i did it now i want to make more gape between dash

Comment: ok did it by doing   circleLayer.lineDashPattern = [6,6] , thank u so much

Comment: @ShahzadAli Use `circleLayer.lineDashPattern = [10,15]`. Here 10 is length of red line and 15 is length of white space between the red lines

Comment: bro i have to do one thing when i give aspect ratio there is a problem in circle

Comment: @ShahzadAli Yes. _"in a square view"_ I said that in answer. View should have equal width and height to use this method. If not you should use `UIBezierPath(arcCenter` method.

Comment: bro can u please give me example to do this , because if i use equal width and height its very small in big screen like xr and x

Comment: bro when i add image or view in this circle by adding contraint it does not affect  contraint does not set to the circle

Comment: @ShahzadAli How do you add image or view in this circle?

Comment: i try both view and image and add contrainsts but when i run contrainst does not affect

Comment: @ShahzadAli You are adding constraint wrongly. Post another question with relevant details

Answer (score 0):

Draw the path using the circle path variant of `UIBezierPath`

```
shapeLayer.path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: frame.size.width * 0.5, y: frame.size.height * 0.5), radius: frame.size.width * 0.5, startAngle: 0, endAngle: .pi * 2, clockwise: true)
```